# spacing between the paragraphs in lyx?

Tags: fonts, lyx

I am writing my thesis using the standard report class. I want the TOC to have bold font for the chapters and the section but not for subsection. I use the following in the preamble

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{-12pt}
```

and have attached the output of this below. [image]

How to unbold the section and the subsection headings ?

I do not get the desired output if I used the following command

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
```

Comment: The command for normal font increase the size to the default size and unbolds it but I do not want the default size.

Comment: It looks like the sort of customization you are looking for may be offered by the koma-script document classes. I advise trying koma-script report first, and looking up the customization options in the koma-script manual.

Comment: It can also be done with the `titletoc` package, which comes with `titlesec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
```

If you want the corresponding page numbers to have the same font size (or another size), use

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
```

Comment: Hi, that removed the bold but again it increased the font size. I want to keep the size but remove the bold.

Comment: What is the base size font of your document?

Comment: I am using non-Tex font and using Times New Roman with 12 as the base size

Comment: Not a fine choice in my opinion (I mean – Times). Try my modified code.

Comment: It's there in my thesis guideline so I will have to stick to that.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!

Comment: What will be the code to reduce the corresponding page number font to the same size as the section/subsection heading ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41327/discussion-between-curious-and-bernard).